# Nesting string format

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I'm writing some reports, and I'd like to know if there's a simpler way to obtain the following behavior.

```
>>> '{:-^60}'.format('Percentage used: {:.2%}'.format(.4))
'------------------Percentage used: 40.00%-------------------'
```

As you can see I'm centering the text and then printing a number formated to percentage. But I'm using a format function inside another. If possible I'd like to do the same in a single function, kind of the following.

```
'$SOMETHING GOES HERE'.format(header = 'Percentage Used:',percentage = .4)
```

Of course I'm looking for a general solution, that would work with all, or most, of the formating options, not just to alignment

Thanks.

Comment: It seems like your problem is inherently nested. Imagine you wanted to format a pair of two numbers, giving each at least 3 chars, and making the whole pair take at least 10. I can't see how you'd write that other than something like `'{:10}'.format('({:3}, {:3})'.format(1,2))`. It's the same thing here. It's the whole string you need to center, not any particular element, so you have to format the formatted string. @wim is right that `center` is probably more readable, but it's effectively equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, mostly I'm looking for some ideas. I don't see how you could do it either, but maybe other functions or something could do the trik. Like the one from @wim. However I do think that what I'd like to do is limited by the format function itself.

Comment: If you're looking for something more powerful and flexible (but complex) than the built-in `format`, for a few years around the time `format` was being discussed, people suggested all kinds of alternatives, and coded up libraries that implemented most of them. Try searching PyPI, and maybe the ActiveState recipe collection (because this was happening while PyPI was still in development) and maybe you'll find something that does what you need. (I don't have any specific recommendations.)

Comment: Oh, also, there's a pure Python reference implementation of `str.format` for Python 2.x; you could probably port that to 3.x pretty easily, then add in whatever extensions you wanted.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I'll need it for this project, but I'll consider it for any future ones

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A more readable option might be `str.center`

```
>>> 'Percentage used: {:.2%}'.format(.4).center(60, '-')
'------------------Percentage used: 40.00%-------------------'
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves the problem at hand. However it's not quite general. But as @abarnert commented, what I want to do is probably inherently nested